# Facebook App Comment Box on Graph API Posts via javascript?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-wall

I have successfully pulled my wall posts via jQuery and the Graph API.   I am wanting to add a drop down comment box link to EACH post (basically a replica of my wall).  I have not seen anywhere where one could do this.  I am pretty sure I pull the `actions` so the comment can be sent directly to that specific post.

See my app here: [My Wall App with HTML](http://www.facebook.com/BurkettRestaurantEquipment?sk=app_175743219164675)

As you can see it only DISPLAYs what is on my wall.  I just want to have a little user interaction with like buttons and a comment box dropdown for each.

I have used jQuery and an .html page to create the app.  I believe it has something to do with the `stream.publish`.  Anyone with any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a `stream.publish`, then the users can comment on the posts. This may not be what you are looking for.

`stream.publish` will require more permissions (`publish_stream` is also the permission). This is also used to post on the wall as that user (So if you are only doing it as the company, then this may not be the best approach, unless you do it in some sort of admin script)

You also have to A) Allow the user to turn off auto publish before they enter your application and B) Show the user what you are going to publish as them. (Facebook Policy).

Once you ask for `publish_stream` in you permissions then a facebook post is done the same way as if you were asking the user to post something:

```
//The message the user will post on their wall
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'name!',
    link: 'http://www.facebook.com/',
    picture: 'http://badge.png',
    caption: 'CAPTION!',
    description: 'DESCRIPTION!',
    message: 'MESSAGE!'
},
function (response) {
    //Nothing needed here
});
```

Comment: Interesting.  I DO want users to comment on the posts.  For all other posts we can just use our Wall.  I have been looking into `stream.publish` and it looks like it is in the process of depreciating the REST API.  It says to POST a Post object to the feed connection of the User object which I am trying to make sense of now.